# syuzhet package - extracting words evaluated by sentiment score

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I'm using syuzhet package for sentiment analysis. It is very simple for usage but I cannot find method/function where it could return all the evaluated words from sentence. It is returning only data frame with count of values correspond to eg. anger, anticipation, surprise, ..., negative, positive. But how can I get back particular words which are considered e.g. as a positive or negative...

```
text <- c("I love it. It's awesome!", 'Im positively surprised.', 'very bad alrighty then.', 'something is not good.')
pander::pandoc.table(syuzhet::get_nrc_sentiment(syuzhet::get_sentences(text))[,9:10])
```

Comment: The same answer was provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49093332/sentiment-analysis-r-syuzhet-nrc-word-emotion-association-lexicon?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Download https://github.com/mjockers/syuzhet/blob/master/R/sysdata.rda

and open it in R or RStudio.

Once that's loaded, do:

`View(nrc)` to see all the words and what emotion they are considered, or the other dataframes for the +/- valence

Comment: loaded and I'm getting 59.732 observation. Then I tried View(nrc) and getting: Error in View : object 'nrc' not found

Comment: 59732 observations? That sounds wrong...... click this exact link: https://github.com/mjockers/syuzhet/blob/master/R/sysdata.rda?raw=true there should be 4 data.frames inside